# adding (list of) lists to csv using pandas dataframe or anything else python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have 10 lists with thousands of rows, for example:

l1 = ['a1', 'a2', ...],
   l2 = ['1', '2', ...],
   ...,
   l10 = ['abc', 'sde',...]

the count of rows of all of them is the same. I would like to create a CSV file like:

```
name reg... address

'a1' '1'... 'abc'

'a2' '2'... 'sde'
```

First I thought using pandas DataFrame:(I only used 103 first rows for testing)

```
data = [l1, l2,..., l10]
lables = ['name', 'reg', ...,'address']    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=labels)
....
```

I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "ch.py", line 122, in 
>      status_list, retrieved_at_list, source_url_list)
>    File "ch.py", line 95, in charity
>      df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=labels)
>    File "C:\Users\MON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site packages\
>   pandas\core\frame.py", line 369, in **init**
>      arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
>    File "C:\Users\MON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\
>   pandas\core\frame.py", line 6284, in _to_arrays dtype=dtype)
>     File "C:\Users\MON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\
>   pandas\core\frame.py", line 6363, in _list_to_arrays
>      coerce_float=coerce_float)
>    File "C:\Users\MON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\
>   pandas\core\frame.py", line 6420, in _convert_object_array
>      'columns' % (len(columns), len(content)))
>
> AssertionError: 10 columns passed, passed data had 103 columns

Then I tried to use:

```
data = [l1, l2,..., l10]
with open('charity.csv', 'w') as  ch_list:
        wr = csv.writer(ch_list, lineterminator='\n')
        wr.writerows(data)
```

But I got all of the data of l1 to l10 in one column.

I have two questions:

1- How can I solve my problem? In terms of performance, I prefer to use pandas DataFrame, however, I am open to any new suggestions.

2-What is the meaning of the error I got for DataFrame and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem (answer for 2nd question):**
Error arises due to way of passing parameters.

Consider the code:

```
import pandas as pd
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2=['a','b','c','d']
values = [l1,l2]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['p', 'q', 'r', 's'])
df2.head()

    p   q   r   s
0   1   2   3   4
1   a   b   c   d
```

The problem is columns passed are interpreted as rows (see pandas doc). Hence, each item of values is a row and length of a row is total number of columns which is 4 here.

**Solution:**
Right way of passing parameters

```
d = {'num':l1, 'char':l2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head()
    char  num
0   a     1
1   b     2
2   c     3
3   d     4
```

Comment: I found this page https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_saving_dataframe_as_csv/ and I noticed that the problem is I used a list instead of a dictionary when I came back to put a note I saw @Prashant 's note which is less code and more simple

Comment: @G.Hak. Thanks for the appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

> 2-What is the meaning of the error I got for DataFrame and how can I
>   solve it?

Your error says that `data` has 103 entries while `labels` have 3 column headers. You can use above solution.

EDIT: based on OP's comment, seems like below is the solution

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
l2 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
l3 = [1,2,3]
labels=['name', 'reg', 'address']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([l1, l2, l3]), columns=labels)
```

Output:

```
    name    reg  address
0   a1      c1     1
1   a2      c2     2
2   a3      c3     3
```

Comment: thanks for your help I tried both of solutions and got the same error. The problem is the lists are not like
l1 = ['a1', 1, 'c1']
l2 = ['a2',2,'c2']
but it is like
l1 = ['a1', 'a2']
l2 = ['1',2']
let's say that each list is the  value for a column and  I want the output that you mentioned above

Comment: @G.Hak. see the edit. If that solves the problem, I will edit my entire answer.

Comment: thank you it solved the problem, however, I  am worried about performance issue as each list has thousands of rows

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'l%i'%i:data[i] for i in range(len(data))})
```